# Почему при клике на кнопку не выводит содержимое массива в <div>?

Tags: javascript

```
let p = [];
let a1 = document.querySelector('.a-1');
let b1 = document.querySelector('.b-1');
let c1 = document.querySelector('.c-1');

b1.onclick = () => {
  a2 = a1.value;
  p.innerHTML = a2;
  c1.innerHTML = p;
};
```

Comment: верстку самим придумать?

Comment: Я не уверен, что ты понимаешь, что делаешь, но если сильно хочется, то можешь написать вот так `c1.innerHTML = p.innerHTML`.

Comment: `c1.innerHTML = a2;`

Answer (score 2):

Обычно люди не пытаются написать стихи, если не знают слова. Вы почему-то пытаетесь методом тыка что-то кодить, не зная синтаксис языка... - а вдруг получится. А не получается. Надо прочитать хотя бы первые несколько пунктов, ознакомиться с основами → http://learn.javascript.ru/

Кажется вы хотели что-то такое)

```js
let p = [];
let a1 = document.querySelector('.a-1');
let b1 = document.querySelector('.b-1');
let c1 = document.querySelector('.c-1');

b1.onclick = function() {
  let a2 = a1.value; // В переменную a2 записалось значение инпута
  p[0] = a2; // Это значение также добавилось в массив - под нулевым носером
  c1.innerHTML = p[0]; // Из массива достали нулевой элемент - добавили его в HTML.
};

/*
  a2 незачем было создавать, можно было писать p[0] = a1.value; и всё.
  А если уж создали, разумнее было бы c1.innerHTML = a1;
*/
```

```html
<input class="a-1" value="Проверка">
<button class="b-1">Клик</button>

<p class="c-1"></p>
```

Но не надо давать переменным названия "a1, b1, p"... как только их станет чуть больше 3-х штук, быстро начнете путать, кто-чей родственник. Лучше чуть дольше печатать, но понимать, что происходит в коде.

А массив - по определению должен хранить нумерованный список элементов. Нет смысла создавать массив, если там должна храниться просто одна строка. Для этого есть обычные переменные. `let str = "ваша строка"; alert(str);`

Варант получше:

```js
let strFromInput; // Просто переменная, в которой можно хранить вашу строку.
// Есть смысл его создавать только если позже в коде эта строка будет нужна еще.

let input = document.querySelector('.a-1');
let button = document.querySelector('.b-1');
let paragraph = document.querySelector('.c-1');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  paragraph.innerHTML = strFromInput = input.value;
  // Прям в одной строчке - значение сначала присвоится переменной 'strFromInput'
  // а потом попадет в innerHTML.
});
```

```html
<input class="a-1" value="Проверка">
<button class="b-1">Клик</button>

<p class="c-1"></p>
```